# Google Chrome: no text displayed

Tags: html, google-chrome, text, google-font-api

I have come across a strange issue. I can see the website: http://fuuuu.net with every browser correctly. My friends here in Europe too.

However, every chrome user from India I have talked with doesn't see any text, although they are using the newest version.

How can that be?

This is a screenshot of what it looks like for them:
[image]

Comment: Do the users in India see text with other browsers?

Comment: yes they do! With Firefox for example!

Comment: Okay, that rules out a few possibilities then; I was initially assuming that the connection was blocked to that site. What exactly do the people encountering the error see?

Comment: I guess they do not all fake their user agent, because why would they...? Do they have something in the error console of Chrome? What do they get if they directly request one of the used font files, e.g. http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v5/VTBnrK42EiOBncVyQXZ7jw7aC6SjiAOpAWOKfJDfVRY.woff2

Comment: If they directly try to request the font, the browser asks for download.  Furthermore I added a screenshot of what these people get and no, they don't fake their user agent.

Comment: Is everyone on the same version of chrome? cache has been fully cleared with a hard reload?

Comment: Everything cleared and reloaded many times already :) One is for example using Chrome 43.0.2357